# Code pattern when wanting to use Flutter's LayoutBuilder inside a Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-layoutbuilder

I have a Column with two elements A and B. A has a fixed height and B is supposed to fill the rest of the screen. Within B I want to make layout decisions based on the height of B via a `LayoutBuilder()`.

If I using the `Column()`-widget normally the BoxConstraint for B is given as infinitive. Is there a good pattern for this problem that gives a finite height for B?

Answer (score 0):

Use `Mediaquery`

`Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;`

on Container B
`height: size.height - containerAFixedHeight`

Comment: Is ther a way to access the containerHeight at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your `LayoutBuilder()` in an `Expanded` (or a `Flexible` if you don't want it expanded) widget and then you can use the maxHeight constraint of the LayoutBuilder at runtime.

```
class MyColumnWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyColumnWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        /// Widget "A":
        Container(height: 100, color: Colors.red),

        /// Widget "B":
        Expanded(
          child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (_, ct) {
            print(" Constraints(h,w): ${ct.maxHeight}, ${ct.maxWidth}");
            return Container(color: Colors.blue);
          }),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a test in Chrome browser:

[image]

Which prints `Constraints(h,w): 460, 500` to terminal. Without `Expanded` it prints `infinity` for height constraint.